# Dataframe slicing with string values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a string dataframe that I would like to modify. I need to cut off each row of the dataframe at a value say A4 and replace other values after A4 with -- or remove them. I would like to create a new dataframe that has values only upto the string "A4".  How would i do this?

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']
values = [['A1', 'A2','A3','A4','A5','A6'],['A1','A3','A2','A5','A4','A6'],['A1','A2','A4','A3','A6','A5'],['A2','A1','A3','A4','A5','A6'], ['A2','A1','A3','A4','A6','A5'],['A1','A2','A4','A3','A5','A6']]
input = pd.DataFrame(values, columns)

columns = ['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6']
values = [['A1', 'A2','A3','A4','--','--'],['A1','A3,'A2','A5','A4','--'],['A1','A2','A4','--','--','--'],['A2','A1','A3','A4','--','--'], ['A2','A1','A3','A4','--','--'],['A1','A2','A4','--','--','--']]
output =  pd.DataFrame(values, columns)
```

Comment: I don't see the string `'A4'` anywhere, can you be more specific about what exactly you're trying to do? Looking at the accepted answer, I'm thinking that a DataFrame might not even be the best data structure for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a small function, that will take an array, and modify the values after your desired value:

```
def myfunc(x, val):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] == val:
            break
    x[(i+1):] = '--'
    return x
```

Then you need to `apply` the function to the dataframe in a rowwise (`axis = 1`) manner:

```
input.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x, 'A4'), axis = 1)


0   1   2   3   4   5
c1  A1  A2  A3  A4  --  --
c2  A1  A3  A2  A5  A4  --
c3  A1  A2  A4  --  --  --
c4  A2  A1  A3  A5  A4  --
c5  A2  A1  A4  --  --  --
c6  A1  A2  A4  --  --  --
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will have values more than `A4`

`df.replace('A([5-9])', '--', regex=True)`

```
     0   1   2   3   4   5
c1  A1  A2  A3  A4  --  --
c2  A1  A3  A2  --  A4  --
c3  A1  A2  A4  A3  --  --
c4  A2  A1  A3  --  A4  --
c5  A2  A1  A4  A3  --  --
c6  A1  A2  A4  A3  --  --
```